Jupyter notebook permission error [Errno 13]
I'm having some issues with opening Jupyter. I just installed Anaconda, but got an error when I try to write "Jupyter notebook" in terminal.
C:\Users\Dell>jupyter notebook
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:20.984 ServerApp] Extension package jupyter_lsp took 0.1255s to import
[W 2024-07-11 00:13:20.984 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2024-07-11 00:13:21.430 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:23.888 ServerApp] Extension package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 2.4530s to import
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:23.888 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:23.903 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:23.903 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:23.921 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:24.984 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:24.984 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.064 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.064 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.064 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.074 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.091 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Dell
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.091 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.1 is running at:
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.091 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=3c1591dc4ea08e01670cdcf9d838e756a46f9ee76df52334
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.091 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=3c1591dc4ea08e01670cdcf9d838e756a46f9ee76df52334
[I 2024-07-11 00:13:25.091 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
**[E 2024-07-11 00:13:25.093 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\jpserver-8224.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 623, in launch_instance
    serverapp.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3119, in start
    self.start_app()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3023, in start_app
    self.write_browser_open_files()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2890, in write_browser_open_files
    self.write_browser_open_file()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2913, in write_browser_open_file
    with open(self.browser_open_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-8224-open.html'**

Can you help me? tks
I'm trying open jupyter notebook.

This looks like a recent known issue with permission in directory C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\runtime. You can in the meantime work around this by specifying a different runtime directory by overriding the environment variable JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR

I reinstalled my windows. After this i could not open my jupyter notebook. Doing this solved my problem :
Create a New Environment:
If you are facing issues with a specific environment, try creating a new one:
bash

conda create -n myenv python=3.10
conda activate myenv
conda install jupyter

